# Vue js Addition of multiple times from moment time

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, momentjs, vue-component

[This is how my function renders the value as subtotal of each punch_in and punch_out and now i want Total of every subtotal as displayed in above table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ad3mE.png)

This is how my function renders the value as subtotal of each punch_in and punch_out and now i want Total of every subtotal as displayed in above table

This is my function where total time from punch_in and punch_out is calculated
  but my concern is how to add those into one variable as an valid time, Any help is appreciated

I Want output as addition for above time would be like : 01:13:15 + 02:00:05  = 03:13:20

```
 calculate_time : function(end,start)
 {                       
      if(start!=null){
           this.$in = start; 
      }
      else if(end!=null){
            this.$out = end; 
            this.$diff = moment.utc(moment(this.$out).diff(moment(this.$in))).format("HH:mm:ss");                          
            return this.$diff;
      } 
  }
```

Comment: Can you please create same example in jsFiddle?

Comment: Its integrated with laravel so cant run on jsFiddle

Comment: I have tried with array for total but its giving infinite loop

Comment: Create a fiddler with the problem in vue part, I guess that you can able to set up indepently.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/dhairyapatel/s7agqz8m/1/

Comment: here it is do watch the SS from above post